# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an old database. Am uploading it into SQL using phpmyadmin But when I want to import it I get an error. It seems the first table even cannot get imported:

```
CREATE TABLE `manager` (
  `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
  `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `deposit` VARCHAR( 50 ) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
)
TYPE = MYISAM
 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_new_ci
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TYPE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_new_ci' at line 7

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you search for a solution? "MyISAM was the default storage engine from MySQL 3.23 until it was replaced by InnoDB in MariaDB and MySQL 5.5" ([Source](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/myisam-storage-engine/))

Comment: Don't tag wrog dbms please.

Comment: `utf8_new_ci` is probably wrong, too.

Answer (score 1):

ENGINE=MyISAM is what you should be using I believe.  Also, its probably a good idea to encapsulate your field names like this :

`username` and `password` just to prevent mysql/mariadb picking them up as reserved words.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TYPE is not a valid table_option in Mysql 8, see Manual at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html. There is a list of all valid table_options beginning in line 110.

> I have an old database

Maybe you can give us more information about your used database by runing the mysql command

```
SELECT VERSION();
```